# ES6 Style Import: Trouble requiring markdown-it in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I have a vue component and I'd like to pull in an NPM package, but I'm unsure of the ES6 syntax.  I have a laravel application that uses babel to translate from ES6, in case you're wondering.  I apologize for the super-entry-level question, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it

The documentation shows the required() syntax, as if I was running vanilla node (I think; javascript is not my primary language)

```
// node.js, "classic" way:
var MarkdownIt = require('markdown-it'),
md = new MarkdownIt();
var result = md.render('# markdown-it rulezz!');
```

However, I'd like to import it like this:

```
import Csrf from './../Form/Csrf'; // Vue component
import { Validator, mixin as validator_mixin } from 'simple-vue-validator'; // Other package I'm pulling in
// Package I can't get to pull in correctly
import { MarkdownIt } from 'markdown-it';
```

If I try and use that as a constructor, I get:

```
"TypeError: _markdownIt.MarkdownIt is not a constructor"
```

If I console.log() it, I get null.  PhpStorm highlights it as though it can't resolve the package.  If I dig through the package, it appears like they're actually exporting the module I think that I'm importing.  Any input would be appreciated.

Using it as a constructor and getting the error makes me think I'm going in the right direction because of what appears to be a "protected" property shown in the output.

Comment: Have you tried removing the curly braces around `MarkdownIt` in the import statement?

Comment: That did it! I didn't realize the difference between a named import and non-named.  I thought it was syntactic sugar vs. the more verbose way.  I apologize for asking such an RTM type question.

Comment: and more importantly thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the curly braces solved the issue for me, per James' reply.  I apologize for the basic-brogrammer question.